# Get raw keys from Bouncy Castle Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I am working with both C and Java implementations for ECDSA. C implementation is using raw formats - 32-byte private key, 64-byte public key, 64-byte signature.

I am creating keys in Java using Bouncy Castle:

```
    public static KeyPair GenerateKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
        KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");

        g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

        return g.generateKeyPair();
    }
```

and want to store them as byte arrays, as I need to export them to my C application later on. I noticed that:

```
        KeyPair vendorKeys = GenerateKeys();
        for (byte byt : vendorKeys.getPublic().getEncoded()) {
            System.out.println("byt: " +  byt);
        }
```

will return bytes of Public key, but length is wrong. I guess it is related to format which is `X.509` for PublicKey and `PKCS#8` for private. Looking for help I found out that there are some classes in Java like `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` which should help me get raw key, but wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You should be able to cast private and public key to `ECPrivateKey` and `ECPublicKey` respectively and then get the required parameters using `getD()` and `getQ()`.

Comment: @Topaco: if you use the ones in `org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces`; standard JCE is different. And `BigInteger` doesn't give you a fixed-size encoding, and even the X9.62 encoding from Bouncy `ECPoint` isn't _exactly_ right. However you can get the _signature_ in fixed format with Bouncy '{hash}with{PLAIN-,CVC-}ECDSA' _or_ SunEC 9+ '{hash}withECDSAinP1363format'. Michal: there are several existing Qs on getting 'raw' keys _into_ JCE, but for getting them out the closest I can find are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299691/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347513/ .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - I was referring to BouncyCastle (`getD()` and `getQ()` are used by BC), but thanks for the clarification. I made it clearer in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key or the x and y coordinates of the public key can be determined with BouncyCastle via its implementations `ECPrivateKey` and `ECPublicKey`. With `getD()` the private and with `getQ()` the public key can be determined, e.g.:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.util.BigIntegers;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
...
ECPublicKey publickKey = (ECPublicKey)vendorKeys.getPublic();
ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey)vendorKeys.getPrivate();
byte[] rawPrivate = BigIntegers.asUnsignedByteArray(privateKey.getD());
byte[] x = publickKey.getQ().getAffineXCoord().getEncoded();
byte[] y = publickKey.getQ().getAffineYCoord().getEncoded();        
byte[] rawPublic = ByteBuffer.allocate(x.length + y.length).put(x).put(y).array();

System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(rawPrivate));
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(rawPublic));
```

The public key here for secp256r1 always has a length of 64 bytes. The private key is 32 bytes in size, but can also be smaller.

---

dave_thompson_085 has pointed out the built-in Java implementations for `ECPublicKey` and `ECPrivateKey` in his comment (`java.security.interfaces`). Here the corresponding methods for the private and public key are `getS()` and `getW()`, respectively.
This implementation does not automatically pad with leading 0x00 values in the case of an x or y smaller than 32 bytes, so this must be done manually. Therefore, the BouncyCastle approach is probably more convenient for you, also because you already use BouncyCastle.

Comment: I had to rename `getD()` to `getS()`, `getQ()` to `getW()`, `getAffineXCoord()` to `getAffineX()` same for `YCoord`, but it works great now! I guess API changed between versions? Any tips how to do opposite, from raw key create a bouncy castle?

Comment: @Michał - By your change you apply the built-in Java implementation instead of BC's (s. the last part in my answer). You can do that, but x and y are not automatically padded.

Comment: @Michał - Regarding the other way around, you can find various posts on SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30445997/9014097) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31435160/9014097).